# Can flask-restful return Response object?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

When implementing REST API with Flask-Restful, I wanted to return a Flask's *Response* object, because it is flexible and easy to use. For example:

```
return Response(
            response=jsonify({
                "data": {
                    "import_id": import_id
                }
            }),
            status=201,
            mimetype="application/json"
        )
```

But looks like flask-restless doesn't support such a thing:

```
2019-08-05 08:52:30,077 werkzeug     INFO     172.21.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2019 08:52:30] "POST /imports HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2019-08-05 08:52:30,078 werkzeug     ERROR    Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 293, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 507, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 45, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable
```

If there are any workaround to use Response? If not, how can I return a mimetype with *flask-restfull*?

Comment: flask-restful or flask-restless? You seem to mention both.

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand Flask-Restful, restless was just a mistype

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work by itself. How does the code around your return vaue look? A hello world example works fine. Unsure what tries to iterate over your Response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jsonify()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) function returns a [`flask.Response()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#response-objects) object, while [`json.dumps(obj)`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.dumps) Serializes `obj` to a JSON-formatted string.

```
....
from Flask import json, Response

....
   return Response(
        response=json.dumps({
            "data": {
                "import_id": import_id
            }
        }),
        status=201,
        mimetype="application/json"
    )
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.